# Possible wrong close review?

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-close, disputed-flags

I've flagged [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31615761/php-strange-condition-checking) as **Unclear what you're asking** but I received a **disputed**.

I Know that a *close flag* goes to *close post review queue* and no to moderators, so is there a way to review it again? May someone else flag this? O should I flag for moderator intervention? Because I really can't understand what the OP is asking,

Comment: What was the UTC time when you flag-ed that?

Comment: Now I am on mobile and I can't see the exactly UTC time but now in my flag summary sayas **22 hours ago** and the post is **22 hours old**

Comment: OK, thanks, that is close enough :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've found the reviewtask that disputed your flag.

This [Triage task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8920195) shows three members that voted 'Should be Improved'. That is opposite to 'Close' hence the dispute.

To be honest I think 'Close' is the correct choice here. There is not much that can be improved by us, the OP needs to provide extra information, a proper test case, clarify what doesn't work, etc.

Unfortunately there is no way to turn back events and you will have to bear the burden of that disputed flag until the end of time ...

Comment: Good find on the triage - it's also in http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/8928044 at present :)

Comment: Yes, in that triage task I was the only one giving it **unsalvagable** because (as you said) only the OP can add details and in doing so I would not have "clogged" the **Help and improvement** review queue. Anyway, thank you for your answer and your research! Now the post is on hold as **Unclear what you're asking** (that's what I wanted) and I know that the review task that closed the post wasn't the one that I flagged...and I will *bear the burden of that disputed flag until the end of time* ... But this is like saying aloud something right on a square and not being heard... 

Comment: I close voted it and that did put it in the CVQ. I have 155 disputed flags and searching for disputed flag on meta gives you...enough posts to spend a Sunday with joy and amazement. Don't let those flags influence you to much.